# Send a message with multiple informations

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Good evening, having tried to make a system to know who invited someone, how many uses has this invitation (but I didn't succeed so I call you)... As soon as a new member arrives on the Discord.
I want this message to be sent in a message.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Tracking new members.

To track when a new member joins a server, you can listen to your client's [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) event.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  // Code in here is executed whenever
  // someone joins a server the bot is
  // also in.
});
```

#### Sending a message through your client.

**1.** In order to send a message, you first have to acquire the channel to send said message *to*. A [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of [GuildChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel)s is available with [`Guild.channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels). Unless you're using the channel's ID in the next step, you should filter the Collection to contain only [TextChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel)s with [`Collection.filter`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter).

```js
const channels = member.guild.channels.filter(channel => channel.type === 'text');
```

**2.** Assuming you have the ID of the channel, you can use [`Map.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) (a Collection is a Map, but a Map is not a Collection) to retrieve the channel. Otherwise, you can find it with [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find), or simply select the first with [`Collection.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=first).

```js
const channel = channels.get('someID');
```

*or*

```js
const channel = channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'welcome');
```

*or*

```js
const channel = channels.first();
```

**3.** To send a message to the channel, you can use [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send). Keep in mind, it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```js
channel.send(`Hello, ${member}!`)
  .catch(console.error);
```

#### Putting the two together.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  const channels = member.guild.channels.filter(channel => channel.type === 'text');
  const channel = channels.get('someID');

  if (!channel) return console.error('Unable to find specified welcome channel!');

  channel.send(`Hello, ${member}!`)
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

---

#### Sending a message through a Webhook.

Alternatively, you could create a Webhook, which would be more efficient.

**1.** To create the Webhook in Discord, navigate to the channel's options, click on `Webhooks`, then `Create Webhook`. Customize your Webhook as you wish, and then copy the link.

> ```html
> https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/THIS_IS_THE_ID/THIS_IS_THE_TOKEN
> ```

**2.** Back to your code, you can create a [Webhook Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/WebhookClient) via its constructor.

```js
const webhookID = 'pasteTheIDHere';
const webhookToken = 'pasteTheTokenHere';

const webhook = new Discord.WebhookClient(webhookID, webhookToken);
```

**3.** Then, you can simply send messages directly to the channel via the Webhook's [`send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/WebhookClient?scrollTo=send) method.

```js
webhook.send(`Hello ${member}!`)
  .catch(console.error);
```

#### Implementation.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  const webhookID = 'pasteIDHere';
  const webhookToken = 'pasteTokenHere';

  const webhook = new Discord.WebhookClient(webhookID, webhookToken);

  webhook.send(`Hello, ${member}!`)
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

If you didn't have direct access to the Discord server, you could use [`TextChannel.createWebhook()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createWebhook) to create the Webhook for you. Then, you'd store the ID and token for each guild's "welcome" Webhook, and use the code above.

---

#### Tracking invites.

To track what invite was used to join the server, you have to track invites themselves.

**1.** In the client's [`ready`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-ready) event, create a new object to hold [Invite](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Invite)s.

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  client.invites = {};
});
```

**2.** Loop through the client's guilds, and add the invites from each into the object. You can acquire the invites within a guild using [`Guild.fetchInvites()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchInvites) (returns a Promise).

```js
for (const [id, guild] of client.guilds) {
  guild.fetchInvites()
    .then(invites => client.invites[id] = invites)
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

**3.** Back to the `guildMemberAdd` event, you need to check which invite has been used. You can do so by checking whether or not it exists, or which one went up in uses ([`Invite.uses`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Invite?scrollTo=uses)).

```js
member.guild.fetchInvites()
  .then(invites => {
    const existing = client.invites[member.guild.id];

    client.invites[member.guild.id] = invites;

    const invite = invites.find(invite => !existing.get(invite.code) || existing.get(invite.code).uses < invite.uses); 
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

---

#### Putting everything together.

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  client.invites = {};

  for (const [id, guild] of client.guilds) {
    guild.fetchInvites()
      .then(invites => client.invites[id] = invites)
      .catch(console.error);
  }
});
```

```js
// Any time the client joins a guild, you should also add their invites to the cache.

client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
  guild.fetchInvites()
    .then(invites => client.invites[id] = invites)
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  member.guild.fetchInvites()
    .then(invites => {
      const existing = client.invites[member.guild.id];

      client.invites[member.guild.id] = invites;

      const inviteUsed = invites.find(invite => !existing.get(invite.code) || existing.get(invite.code).uses < invite.uses); 

      const channels = member.guild.channels.filter(channel => channel.type === 'text');
      const channel = channels.get('someID');

      if (!channel) return console.error('Unable to find specified welcome channel!');

      channel.send(`${member} joined, using an invite from ${inviteUsed.inviter} (${inviteUsed.uses} use${inviteUsed.uses !== 1 ? 's' : '')!`);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me But I already know how to do that, I'm just looking to get the name of the user who invited the person and the number of times the invitation was used (a bit like InviteManager).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS1He.png

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've updated my answer to include what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly well, but can we lower this number if the guest person leaves the Discord (I'm sorry for the inconvenience.)

Thank you again

Comment: Manually changing the `uses` count within the cache would interfere with the way the system detects which invite was used. You could add another property to each invite to track how many users are *present* that used the invite, and change it on `guildMemberAdd` and `guildMemberRemove`.

Comment: Thanks, it's help me. Have a nice day